# Unable to get bitmap from the following uri : Uri imageUri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri()

Tags: android

[image]Project: Open Gallery From a Button in One Activity, Select The Images from there and Display it on the initial Activity screen.

Solution: I know that the solution for the problem above is given but it only deals with the multiple selection of images part and getting the data of the images.

My Problem:

1. From here, i am unable to use the uri data to convert to bitmap and hence store in my image view. I even tried

ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageUri.getPath()) ;

imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); but the image doesn't show

2. How to get dynamic number of image views?
   I want the image views on my activity.xml to be dynamic,i.e it changes its number depending on the number of selections
   for eg: if the user selects 5 images on opening the gallery app, then i want to be able to display the 4 images on the initial Activity screen. If 6 images selected then 6, if 2 then 2. It should change the image view count depending on the number of selections as I dont want to hardcode the number of image views in the xml file.

How i am trying to get the bitmap is by
 Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);

I am getting Unhandled exceptions error , java.io.FileNotFoundException for the getBitmap part below

I have attached my code below

```
    public void onClick(View view){
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE) {
                if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    if(data.getClipData() != null) {
                        int count = data.getClipData().getItemCount(); //evaluate the count before the for loop --- otherwise, the count is evaluated every loop.
                        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
                            Uri imageUri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();

Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),imageUri) ; //MAIN ERROR OVER HERE


//OR

                            ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageUri.getPath()) ; 
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); //STILL NOT WORKING
                        }
                    }
                } else if(data.getData() != null) {
                    String imagePath = data.getData().getPath();
                    ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView); //WANT TO AVOID THIS AND MAKE IMAGE VIEW NUMBER AS DYNAMIC
                    Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please do not add Images of Code . Add code in code format and indicate the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream iStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImageUri);
            byte[] inputData = Utils.getBytes(iStream);
            dbHelper.insertImage(inputData);
```

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/12/23/store-image-android-sqlite-retrieve-it/